# issues with running script to read from mysql and insert into mongo (multithreading issues) using play framework

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, threadpool, quill

I have a script that I want to run to go over mysql table that have around 4M records, and for each one I perform another call another mysql table to get more data, from this data I create a new object and insert it to mongodb.

so basically I want to perform migration from mysql to mongodb

im using quill, which is a library to work with sql on your scala project (QDSL).

```
my script class is very short and looks like:

class MigrateScript @Inject()(dao: PeopleDao) {

  lazy val ctx = new MysqlAsyncContext(SnakeCase, "mysql")

  import ctx._

      def getNextPerson(idx: Int): Future[Person] = {
        val q = quote {
          query[Person].drop(lift(idx)).take(1)
        }
        ctx.run(q.take(1)).map(_.head) recover {
          case t: NoSuchElementException =>
            println(s"problem with index: $idx")
            throw new RuntimeException
        }
      }

      def getPersonKids(personId: Int): Future[List[Kid]] = {
        val q = quote {
          query[Kid].filter(kid => kid.parent_id == lift(personId))
        }
        ctx.run(q)
      }


      def runScript(numberOfRecords: Int): Unit = {
        for (a <- 0 to numberOfRecords) {
          getNextPerson(a).map(person => {
            getPersonKids(person.id).map(kids => {
              // create obj and insert to mongo
              val parentWithKidsObjectToInsert = // creating new object using person & kids

              dao.insert(parentWithKidsObjectToInsert) // this returns Future[String]
            })
          })
        }
      }

}
```

to run it I do it from my controller like this:

```
  def insertMySqlRecordsToMongo(numberOfRecords: Int) = Action { request =>
    mScript.runScript(numberOfRecords)
    Ok
  }
```

issues:

1. when I run it like this the script get stuck after 100+- records and I get errors in my log:

   > java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5
   >   seconds]

and

```
WARN   [ousekeeper] - c.z.h.p.HikariPool(755)        - HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=1m51s17ms).
```

feels like the app is running faster than the mysql connection pool can handle...

2. so I tried to add Await.result above getNextPerson and it works well but very slow. its only inserting 300 records per min which could take few days to go over 4M records...

any solutions please? thanks allot for whoever take the time to understand this :)

Answer (score 0):

I really, really suggest you look into Spark to do this, I sounds like a typical ETL use-case. The problem is that you are materializing thousands of records into memory which is killing your GC and stalling the Futures. Also the fact that you have to do it record by record makes it very, very slow. If you load this into Spark dataframes instead, I'll take waaaay less space because Spark doesn't actually materialize the records into memory (they use an extremely compact binary in-memory serialization which 'spills' to disk if needed) which saves your heap from GC-annihilation. Also it performs the load and transformations for many, many records in parallel. It'll give you the preformance characteristics to make your problem tractable.

Here's roughly what I would do:

1. Load the records into a Spark Dataset using the `spark.read.jdbc`
2. Join the Datasets and the group by the Parent record
3. Write the records out to MongoDB using the [Mongo Spark Collector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/scala/write-to-mongodb/)

The code itself should look something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, SparkSession}
import com.mongodb.spark._
// probably import some other stuff

SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("Load records to mongo")
       // Configure the spark->mongo connector
      .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

case class PersonWithKids(person:Person, kids:List[Kid])

// make sure the MySQL jdbc driver is not the classpath because spark is about to use it
val people = spark.jdbc.read("(select * from people) as data", "jdbc://...").as[Person]
val kids = spark.jdbc.read("(select * from kids) as data", "jdbc://...").as[Kid]
val joined = 
  people
    .joinWith(kids, people("id") === kids("parent_id"))
    .map({case (person, kid) => PersonWithKids(person, List(kid))})
    .groupByKey(_.person)
    .flatMapGroups({case (person, personWithKidIter) => 
        PersonWithKids(person, personWithKidIter.toList.flatMap(_.kids))
    })

// make sure you did stuff correctly
// joined.show()
// joined.take(100).write.json("someFileWhereYouCanDoubleCheck.json")

MongoSpark.save(joined)
```

You'll probably need the following SBT dependencies:

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1" // or 2.4.0 might be latest now
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.3.1" // or 2.4.0 might be latest now
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.1" // or 2.4.0 might be latest now
"org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "2.3.1" // or 2.4.0 might be latest now
```

Good luck!